# Cant receive the data from different layouts of view pager on button click of parent class

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I m using a view pager which has 3 layouts containing different  form's.
i have a button to save the changed data from different layouts
how to get the data from different layouts on button click ??
please help

```
             @Override
            public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Inflate the layout containing a title and body text.



        if(mPageNumber==0)
        {

         //LoginActivity loginActivity=new LoginActivity();
         //System.out.println("Hello"+loginActivity.loginData);
         rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout2, container, false);
        ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.fullnameedit)).setText(name);
        ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.usernameedit)).setText(username);
        ((EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.emailedit)).setText(email);
        ((EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.passedit)).setText(address);
        ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.emailtext)).addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                System.out.println("assssasaas");
                if (((EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.passedit)).getText().toString().compareTo(s.toString()) != 0)
                {
                    // your code ...

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                System.out.println("fsdfhahfadhsf;osd");

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                System.out.println("ighadfigadwfuiqwl");
                if (((EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.passedit)).getText().toString().compareTo(s.toString()) != 0)
                {
                    // your code ...
                    email=((EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.passedit)).getText().toString().toString();
                    System.out.println(email+"editable");
                }
            }
        });


        System.out.println(mPageNumber+" page 0");


        }
        else if(mPageNumber==1)
        {
             rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout3, container, false);
             ((EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.mobileph)).setText(mobileno);
             ((EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.home)).setText(homephone);
             ((EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.cit)).setText(city);
             ((EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.countrry)).setText(country);
             ((EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.postall)).setText(zipcode);
             ((EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.countyy)).setText(country);
             System.out.println(mobileno+" "+homephone+" "+city+" "+country+" "+county+" "+zipcode);
             System.out.println(mPageNumber+" page 1"); 
        }
        else if(mPageNumber==2)
        {
             rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout4, container, false);
             ((EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.birth)).setText(dob);
             ((EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.about)).setText(aboutme);
             System.out.println(mPageNumber+" page 2");
        }
        else if(mPageNumber==3)
        {
             rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater
                        .inflate(R.layout.layout5, container, false);
             ((EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.facebuk)).setText(facebook);
             ((EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.twitterr)).setText(twitter);
             ((EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.myspacee)).setText(icq);
             ((EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.linkedinjn)).setText(linked);
             System.out.println(mPageNumber+" page 3");
        }
        // Set the title view to show the page number.
        //((TextView) rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.button1)).setText(
              //  getString(R.string.title_template_step, mPageNumber + 1));

        return rootView;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

onCreateView() is called only once when your fragment is created. You should add onPageChangeListener to your viewPager and in this listener you should create inflater object and then inflate layout that you want.

Comment: onPageChangeListener will work when the page will be changed ??
because if user changed some data and clicked save button at that moment the changed value will not be reflected if the onPageChangeListener will work on page scroll..